# Outline on Inline-Elements in FF buggy?

Tags: firefox, background, inline, outline

The outline is not placed correct on inline-elements in Firefox. There is a space between background and outline.

Any suggestions to avoid that?

```
strong
{
    background: #3690f0;
    color: white;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9cA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has a bug in drawing outline (see more here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480888). You can workaround utilizing box-shadow:

```
strong
{
    background: #3690f0;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: This works, but is not possible in my case, cause a border makes the element wider and i need the original pixelposition.

Comment: I've updated my answer replacing border with box-shadow property. Please let us know if this works for you :-)

Comment: I came from the future just to tell you that you sir are awesome